# Build CityGML Buildings from OBJ files of OpenDroneMap

Tags: cesium, citygml, opendronemap

I have .obj 3D mesh files after running OpenDroneMap on Drone Images. I want to convert them to CityGML buildings so that I can put them on Cesium Globe.

How can I do this?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: In short: for mere visualization, converting to CityGML seems a bit overkill. Aren't there any other options? There is a fundamental difference between geometric 3D models (such as OBJ) and semantic 3D models (such as CityGML). A semantic one includes 'meaning', thus extra information on top of what you see. A surface in a semantic 3D city model will have attributes (e.g. what kind of surface, the cadastral id of the building, etc.) while one in geometric 3D models won't. Therefore, building CityGML files is a long and intense process. As far as I know, raw LiDAR point clouds are often used (a

Comment: Try asking the people at TU Delft https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/v2aeq3No/025-030.pdf.html  for the code, it is not (?) published as far as I can see...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to visualise the OBJ, going to complex semantic data model is (1) overkill; (2) not necessary; (3) a waste of time.

Cesium supports glTF, and you can just convert to this.

If you want a semantic model, I'd suggest using CityJSON (https://www.cityjson.org) instead. You can program a simple script to convert your OBJ to it (it has the same structure almost) and then convert automatically to CityGML (tutorial: https://www.cityjson.org/help/users/conversion/)

Comment: Thank you. But, how will I go from .obj file to cityjson format?